# Output of cast function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on the usage of the `Cast` function in SQL Server. If I use explicit value as written in the code. The output is 38 which is the correct value. But I would need to use field names instead of direct values(There is only value of Base, escalator here ; Base =1.15 and escalator=0.05. But when I use field names, the output is 37. The data type of Base and escalator fields is float. I also tried using round function inside cast, did not solve the issue. Could someone out here help me with this. My query below:

```
Select CAST((3.05-1.15)/0.05 AS INT) -- returns 38
Select ((3.05-1.15)/0.05) --returns 38
Select cast((3.05-base)/Escalator) as int) from table1 -- I am using field names here. Returns 37
```

Comment: What are the values of base & Escalator? It will be better you you will provide the sample table with data in the text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is likely happening here is that the `base` and `Escalator` columns are some kind of non exact floating point type.  As a result, the following computation results a value which is *slightly* less than 38:

```
(3.05-base) / Escalator = 37.999995 (for example)
```

Then, when casting to integer, the entire decimal component is being truncated, leaving behind just 37.

One possible workaround to prevent this from happening would be to use `NUMERIC` or some other exact type for the `base` and `Escalator` columns.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Numeric(18,3) works in this case for me. Float is not an exact type as you mentioned, but "numeric" is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Decimal` to get rid of the issue

```
DECLARE @Escalator DECIMAL(7, 5) = 0.05
Select ((3.05-1.15)/0.05) --returns 38
Select CAST(((3.05-1.15)/@Escalator) AS INT) -- returns 38
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42f472a509552223d64b11044a361830)

Comment: Here @Escalator can not be int otherwise it will error - division by zero.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. @Escalator type is `Decimal`. I just cast the output value into `INT`

Comment: I was saying that even when you will cast in int, decimal or not it will give the output 38 as from the taken sample values in answer. So, it has not impact. You can check this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dca8d6dd906555fb5ad13645f7569da

Comment: The problem will be raised from the value what they have in the column which we do not know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help. @Varun Shekhar RC

Answer (score 0):

you can use ceiling or floor inbuilt function based on your requirement

```
DECLARE @Escalator float = 0.05
DECLARE @Base float = 1.66
Select ((3.05-1.66)/0.05) --returns 27.8
Select ceiling (((3.05-@Base)/@Escalator)) -- returns 28
Select floor (((3.05-@Base)/@Escalator)) -- returns 27
```